# 'let' vs 'var' in javascript for loops, does it mean that all the for loops using the 'var i =0' should actually be 'let i =0' instead?

Tags: javascript

Since according to [What's the difference between using "let" and "var" to declare a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/javascript-let-keyword-vs-var-keyword), the let keyword has a smaller scope than var when used in a for loop. Does this mean that of all the places where 'for (var i=0...' the actual correct way should be to use let? I can't imagine a case where a developer who was using 'for (var i=0...' would want to have the var i still be visible outside the for loop, meaning that all 'for (var i=0...' are wrong and the correct way is 'for (let i=0...'? Just a yes or no question.

```
function allyIlliterate() {
    //tuce is *not* visible out here

    for( let tuce = 0; tuce < 5; tuce++ ) {
        //tuce is only visible in here (and in the for() parentheses)
    };

    //tuce is *not* visible out here
};

function byE40() {
    //nish *is* visible out here

    for( var nish = 0; nish < 5; nish++ ) {
        //nish is visible to the whole function
    };

    //nish *is* visible out here
};
```

Comment: Judging by the complete split in answers, both with good reasons for and against, I think this might qualify as "primarily opinion-based."

Comment: @ajm I mostly agree, though the question as worded clearly asks whether "all the for loops" are "wrong", and I don't think that's a matter of opinion.

Comment: That's true. It will be interesting to see if the answers maintain the same 50/50 split. :-)

Answer (score 16):

`let` is introduced in Ecma Script 6 - the new javascript version - which is still in development at the time of this writing. Therefore, using `var` will get you across more browsers for the time being.

On the other hand, I urge people to use `let` instead of `var` from now on. I would go ahead and list the reasons but you have already have a link in your post with a great explanation in it. Long story short, `let` helps you avoid the variable hoisting in javascript and keep your variables' scope at just where it needs to be.

#### update

I've forgotten about this post until I recently got an upvote. I'd like to update this statement. I personally use `const` as much as I can these days. If you get into linting your code, which I highly recommend, and use something like airbnb lint rules, it will also tell you to use const. It will make your variables a constant so you will not be able to mutate them once you set their value thus it is not applicable in all cases. `const` and `let` also have advantages in terms of scope over `var` and it is well worth a read. My hierarchy of usage goes as such `const` > `let` > `var`

Comment: ES6 is now ES2015, an finalized standard :)

Comment: Right ... [Check it out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Are you suggesting to use cont for the OPs for loop? Shoudn't a const remain unchanged?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you would want to use `let` there as it will be scoped only to that block.

Additionally, using `let` in this way will let you avoid accidentally creating a closure if you are calling a function in your loop and passing the counter as a parameter.

EDIT: Maybe this should be better put as: Ask yourself if you need to access the value of your variable outside of the loop. If you do, use `var`; in all other cases, use `let`.

Answer (score 8):

The answer is "no", in my opinion:

```
function doSomething( anArray ) {
  for (var i = 0; i < anArray.length; ++i) {
    if (someTest( anArray[i] ))
      break;
  }
  return i === anArray.length ? "test failed" : "test succeeded";
}
```

That's not the prettiest thing in the world, but checking an iterator variable after a loop is at least somewhat idiomatic. It's also possible that a `var i` in one `for` loop is taken advantage of in the same function in a later `for` loop that doesn't repeat the `var`.

Now, whether code like that should be improved in a way that happens to take advantage of `let` is another question. It should be clear however that blindly replacing such uses of `var` with `let` in an existing codebase would be seriously unwise.

Going forward, it's certainly a good idea to keep variable scoping as constrained as possible, but dogmatic rules like "always use `let` and not `var` in `for` loops" can't possibly take into account all the programming problems you may encounter. A "best practice" is "best" until it isn't.

Comment: Actually, it's quite easy to change that function so you can use ```let``` instead of ```var``` and simplify it by removing the ```? :``` operator in the process. Simply set a default return value before you enter the loop and update it before the ```break``` statement.

Comment: @Arjan I understand that; the point is, it's not "wrong" as it is. Would it be better if it were re-written? Well, it's a rare piece of code that wouldn't :)

Comment: Actually you can use let INSTEAD of var in this case. Just move out declaration of i out of for loop (put such line above for loop "let i;" and use the declared i in for loop like this: "for (i=0; i<...)"). This would make your intention more clear as i is explicitly moved out, and also you'll end up without "var"-s in the code so risk of hoisting is not a problem anymore.