# In the for loop the i variable is different each time through the loop

Tags: javascript

The code below is not my code. Can someone explain it? I don't know much JavaScript so I dont really understand it. I think thats why I dont understand how using let in a for loop makes the i variable distinct for each cycle through the loop? Using var should do the same.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>buttons - let and Const</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Buttons</h1>
    <button>Button 0</button>
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
    <button>Button 3</button>
    <button>Button 4</button>
    <button>Button 5</button>
    <button>Button 6</button>
    <button>Button 7</button>
    <button>Button 8</button>
    <button>Button 9</button>
    <script>
      const buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
      
      for(let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
          const button = buttons[i];
          button.addEventListener("click", function() {
              alert("Button " + i + " Pressed");
          }); 
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['let' vs 'var' in javascript for loops, does it mean that all the for loops using the 'var i =0' should actually be 'let i =0' instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32313961/let-vs-var-in-javascript-for-loops-does-it-mean-that-all-the-for-loops-usin) and [What's the difference between using “let” and “var”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011)

Comment: *"Using var should do the same"* ... No. It doesn't

Comment: This is the opposite of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/9029328)

Comment: @charlietfl i feel that i should because i  is different each time through the loop too because i is getting incremented by one.

Comment: Yes it does increment using both var and let....however if you use `var` it will be at it's maximum when the event occurs whereas using let is block scoped and `i` will maintain it's value when event occurs

Comment: @charlietfl yes i know this i am just confused because i dont understand the code. So i know the loop runs no matter what. This part (  ` button.addEventListener("click", function() {
              alert("Button " + i + " Pressed");` ) is ran in the loop but what if i click on a button when the loop is over?

Comment: The loop will definitely be over when the button event occurs. It will run in a few 1000ths of a second

Comment: @charlietfl so why does the code inside the loop still run?

Comment: It runs and creates multiple event listeners and is done faster than you can blink. The difference between `let` and `var` appears when try to access `i` inside the event handler when it fires minutes later.....in computer time, an eternity after loop completes

Comment: @charlietfl ok i get the code now. I dont know any programmers here in oslo so i dont have anyone to ask my beginner level questions so thank you very much charlie!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key difference between `let` and `var` in a for loop can only be seen if you try to access the variable asynchronously. Using `var` the variable gets allocated once, and on every iteration that value will be changed. Using `let` the variable will be allocated in a different memory location at each iteration, and the value of the previous iteration will be copied in the new location. If you access it asynchronously it will refer to that memory location.

```
 for(var i = 0, test = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   // test: 1, 2, 3 -> the same value gets mutated
   // i: 10, 10, 10-> the same value, the loop already finished
   setTimeout(() => console.log("i", i, "test 1", ++test)); 
 }

for(let i = 0, test = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  // test: 1, 1, 1 -> a new "test" got allocated on each iteration
  // i: 0, 1, 2 -> kept at every iteration
  setTimeout(() => console.log("i", i, "test 2", ++test));
}
```

Comment: can you comment a link to where you got this information please? I want to read more about it

Comment: Well the definite answer is always the [spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), but [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) is way more readable

Answer (score 1):

The `let` keyword is used to declare variables with a limited scope.

Here is a great [article](https://codeburst.io/difference-between-let-and-var-in-javascript-537410b2d707) about the differences between `let` and `var`.

From the article :

> let gives you the privilege to declare variables that are limited in scope to the block, statement of expression, unlike var.

In your example `i` will only be available in the scope of the for loop.

Comment: I get the difference between them im just confused because i read like ten minutes ago that "in a for loop the i variable is different each time through the loop" which is weird to me because i feel that var is different each time through the loop to because i is getting incremented by one.