# Is there an easy way in Javascript to add parameterised event listeners to dynamically generated HTML elements?

Tags: javascript

I have an ordered list whose list items are generated using Javascript (as the number of items/their contents is variable), and I would like to add an event listener to each item dependant on which element of the list it is - so I want the 1st item to call `foo(1)`, the 2nd element to call `foo(2)`, the 30th element to call `foo(30)`, etc. However, currently all elements are ending up with a listener identical to that of the last element. Code I'm using is shown below:

```
document.getElementById("mylist").innerHTML = "";
  for (i = 0; i < listitems.length; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.setAttribute("id", "listitem" + i);
    li.addEventListener("click",function(){foo(i)})
    document.getElementById("mylist").appendChild(li);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about if you use let to declare your i variable:

```
document.getElementById("mylist").innerHTML = "";
for (let i = 0; i < listitems.length; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.setAttribute("id", "listitem" + i);
    li.addEventListener("click",function(){foo(i)})
    document.getElementById("mylist").appendChild(li);
}
```

Reference: ['let' vs 'var' in javascript for loops, does it mean that all the for loops using the 'var i =0' should actually be 'let i =0' instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32313961/let-vs-var-in-javascript-for-loops-does-it-mean-that-all-the-for-loops-usin)

Answer (score 0):

You have to try as below to `capture` variable inside `for` loop to set `event listener`. Find `Creating closures in loops: A common mistake` in [this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3a_A_common_mistake).

Update your event listener assignment as `li.addEventListener("click", function(){ var index = i; return foo(index); });`.

Complete code is as below.

```
document.getElementById("mylist").innerHTML = "";
for (i = 0; i < listitems.length; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.setAttribute("id", "listitem" + i);
    li.addEventListener("click", function(){ var index = i; return foo(index); });
    document.getElementById("mylist").appendChild(li);
}
```