# Find all elements with attribute in class

Tags: javascript, html, custom-data-attribute

I would like to select all elements with attribute `[data-direction]` in class `main`

```
<div class="main">
   <div data-direction="top">1</div>
   <div data-direction="top">2</div>
   <div>3</div>
</div>
<div class="main">
   <div data-direction="top">3</div>
   <div>4</div>
   <div data-direction="top">5</div>
</div>
```

So I can select each div with `data-direction` in specific class. Something like: `main[x].style.top = '10px'`

```
myElement = document.querySelectorAll('.main');
main = myElement.querySelectorAll('[data-direction]');

for (var i = 0; i < myElement.length; i++) {
    myElement[i].style.position = 'relative';

    for (var x = 0; x < parallaxStart.length; x++) {
      main[x].style.top = '10px';
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `myElement.querySelectorAll('div[data-direction]');` instead of your code, you need to specific the element, and if you are sure the lenght of main and myElement it's same use one for-loop

Comment: `myElement` and `main` are collections, hence the name should be plural.

Comment: If you want to select all elements that have the attribute `data-direction` and are descendant of an element with the class `main`, you can use `document.querySelectorAll('.main [data-direction]');`; if you want only direct children of the `main` elements, you can use `document.querySelectorAll('.main > [data-direction]');`

Comment: a) Why aren't you setting `position: relative` in CSS? I can't see any advantage setting them in javascript. b.1) You're not setting `position: relative` on your data-direction divs, and b.2) You shouldn't use `top` to move, but `transform: translateY()` to avoid the entire page having to recalculate position.

Comment: What is `parallaxStart`, apart from an array?

Comment: @RickardElimää It was just an example css, the main thing was to select specific divs :) but thank you for advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can target the inner elements inside the loop:

```js
myElement = document.querySelectorAll('.main');

for (var i = 0; i < myElement.length; i++) {
    myElement[i].style.position = 'relative';
    var parallaxStart = myElement[i].querySelectorAll('[data-direction]');
    for (var x = 0; x < parallaxStart.length; x++) {
      parallaxStart[x].style.marginTop = '40px';
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
   <div data-direction="top">1</div>
   <div data-direction="top">2</div>
   <div>3</div>
</div>
<div class="main">
   <div data-direction="top">3</div>
   <div>4</div>
   <div data-direction="top">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any reason for using var in both for-loops instead of let and parallaxStart could also be declared with const in my opinion.

Comment: @Habebit is there a difference in performance? BTW. code works for me :)

Comment: @Matredok https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467642/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-let-and-var-in-javascript (performance) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32313961/let-vs-var-in-javascript-for-loops-does-it-mean-that-all-the-for-loops-usin/32314080 (let vs. var in foor-loops)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach` with `querySelectorAll`, and remember to specify the element like  `div[data-direction]`

```js
const myElementArr = document.querySelectorAll('.main');
myElementArr.forEach(element => {
  element.style.position = 'relative';
  let mains = element.querySelectorAll('div[data-direction]');
  mains.forEach(main => {      
      main.style.top = '10px';
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div data-direction="top">1</div>
  <div data-direction="top">2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div data-direction="top">3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div data-direction="top">5</div>
</div>
```

Reference:

- [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?retiredLocale=it)
- [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector?retiredLocale=it)

Answer (score 0):

Just target all elements with that data attribute within the `.main` classes, and then use [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) and adjust the CSS of the `main` class.

```js
const directions = document.querySelectorAll('.main [data-direction]');

directions.forEach(direction => {
  direction.classList.add('blue');
  direction.closest('.main').classList.add('embolden');
});
```

```css
.embolden { font-weight: bold; }
.blue { color: blue; }
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div data-direction="top">1</div>
  <div data-direction="top">2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div data-direction="top">3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div data-direction="top">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: He need to change css for `main` elements and `data-direction` into  each main, your code don't work for OP situation.

Comment: Easily fixed, @SimoneRossaini.

Answer (score -1):

You need that:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.main').forEach((main) => {
  main.style.position = 'relative';
  main.querySelectorAll('[data-direction]').forEach((x) => {
    x.style.top = '10px';
  })
})
```

Comment: It's a variable.